# trying to copy an email address

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to request some help in pointing out how to change a block of code.  The first block has a copy function in it that I would like to use in place of the "delete" check box ion the second block.  I need to change the "delete" check box to a "copy" check box to copy the email address only.  I need to paste the email address into an email and also a text box to keep track of the emails that have been sent rather than digging through the sent folder.

```
/**$(function() {
  $('.copy-to-clipboard input').click(function() {
    $(this).focus();
    $(this).select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    $(".copied").text("Copied to clipboard").show().fadeOut(2500);
  });
});**/

$(function() {
  $('.copy-cell').click(function() {
    const other = $(this).next('td')
    other.find('input').focus();
    other.find('input').select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    /*$(".copied").text("Copied to clipboard").show().fadeOut(2500);*/
  });
});



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Add / Remove Table Rows Dynamically</title>
<style>
    form{
        margin: 20px 0;
    }
    form input, button{
        padding: 5px;
    }
    table{
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table, th, td{
        border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
    }
    table th, table td{
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: left;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".add-row").click(function(){
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var markup = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + email + "</td></tr>";
            $("table tbody").append(markup);
        });
        
        // Find and remove selected table rows
        $(".delete-row").click(function(){
            $("table tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function(){
                if($(this).is(":checked")){
                    $(this).navigator.cilpboard.writeText();
                }
            });
        });
    });    
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email Address">
        <input type="button" class="add-row" value="Add Row">
    </form>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Select</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="record"></td>
                <td>Peter Parker</td>
                <td>peterparker@mail.com</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" class="delete-row">Delete Row</button>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="userTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Select</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input class="sel" type="checkbox" name="record[]"></td>
            <td>Peter Parker</td>
            <td>peterparker@mail.com</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" class="copy-row">Copy Row</button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".add-row").click(function(){
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var markup = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' class='sel' name='record[]'></td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + email + "</td></tr>";
            $("table tbody").append(markup);
        });
        

 // Copy email only
$(".copy-row").click(function(){
    var data = $("#userTable tbody tr").has('td .sel:checked').map(function(index, row){
        return $(row).find('td:last-child').innerText; // it will target the last cell ( email )
    }).get().join('\n');
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(data);
});
    });    
</script>
```

I have added class="sel" to select the required columns, also changed the checkbox name to record[] ( not necessary may be required if sent to server )

[get()](https://api.jquery.com/get/#get2) - will covert dom object to array

[join('\t')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join); will convert array to string separated by the character specified OR comma ( if without param )

Comment: thanks for the help much appreciated,.  I do see where it looks like the delete row was removed I really need that to still be there.

Comment: I just tested the changes.  If I check the box then click copy, the resulting paste is the entire code block.  Also as I noted above the add rows and delete rows are missing.  In my OP all i want to do is add the JavaScript copy functions at the start of the code block into the html code block right below them and add a copy button .  The Html script is fine the way it is as it add and deletes rows.

Comment: I have added copy email, Note:- the answer gives you an idea, you can do some R&D and do the rest. if you put a little effort it is not that hard.

Comment: Thanks.  I was doing what you suggested about R&D and have things pretty much in hand with the exception of a couple things.   Im using the style user select all in a TD.  Works fine but now I need a copy button.  I can do the button code but when I style it, it doesnt go where I want it to.   I suspect my CSS isnt right.  The other thing is when you refresh the page the entries are cleared from the screen.  Any way to prevent that?  Other than that I think Im good.